# jquery delete source code from a page on load?

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to delete source code from a page using jquery (when the document loads, when an event is triggered, etc.)? I'm not thinking of the .remove() or .hide() methods; I'd like to actually *delete* the code from the page.

Comment: Whic code, javascript or html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because the source code is rendered by the web browser, so unless you plan on deleting the code you send to the client (which seems counter-productive) you will not be able to hide the source code.

However, there are steps you can take to obfuscate the code so that it is more difficult for people to read and understand, but for anyone determined this would only be a small set-back and not an actual hindrance.

Comment: I wasn't planning on using this for security purposes, but I render different types of content depending on if the user has javascript enabled. By default, content for non-js users, then jquery hides that and displays different content if javascript is enabled. I was hoping to delete the non-js code instead of hiding it to get around some other problems with XHTML validation, but it's not a big ordeal if this isn't possible. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

No, what is sent to the client is sent to the client. Changing the DOM does not change the html sent from the server.